# Simpler derivation of Sackur-Tetrode equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas

Is there a reason the following derivation for the [Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation) is not common?  I am teaching a lower undergraduate level class and would like to derive it with simpler terms of only using relative volume.

The equation is:
$$ kn \ln \frac V {n\lambda^3},  $$ 
where $\lambda^3$ is the thermal wavelength cubed, or the quantum volume for one particle.

Since each particle has a volume of $\lambda^3$, the total of number of positions in the volume for a particle is $N = \frac V {\lambda^3}$, and $n$ is the total number of particles.

1. Using the binomial distribution, the definition of $S$ from Boltzmann's equation is:
   $$S = k\ln \Omega = k\ln \biggl[\frac {N!}{n!(N-n)!}\biggr]$$
2. Substituting for $N = \frac V {\lambda^3}$,
   $$S = k \ln\left[\frac {\bigl(\frac V {\lambda^3}\bigr)!}{n!\bigl(\frac V {\lambda^3}-n\bigr)!}\right]$$
3. Using Stirling's approximation:
   $$S = k \biggl[ \frac V {\lambda^3} \ln \biggl(\frac V {\lambda^3}\biggr) -  \biggl(\frac V {\lambda^3}  - n \biggr) \ln \biggl(\frac V {\lambda^3}-n\biggr)  - n \ln (n)\biggr]$$
4. Using the approximation $\ln \bigl(\frac V {\lambda^3}-n\bigr) =  \ln\bigl(\frac V {\lambda^3}\bigr) $ for $\frac V  {\lambda^3} \gg n$
   $$S = k \biggl[ n \ln \biggl(\frac V {\lambda^3}\biggr)  - n \ln (n)\biggr]$$
5. Manipulate algebra.
   $$S = kn \ln \frac V {n\lambda^3}$$

I'd like to use this in my class because it is simpler and cleaner and develops a sort of chemical intuition based on binomial distribution.  However, I want to know if this is correct.  I have seen this equation without the $5/2$ term before.

Edit:  The physical assumption that I think might be invalid is the use of N as $\frac V  {\lambda^3}$.  The binomial distribution is valid when you have n particles that fit into N DISCREET positions.  That would work fine for a box of volume V with N slots separated by partitions.  But in this case, the volume V does not have any partitions and is continuous.  In this case, a volume $\lambda^3$ can fit into positions that are not discreetly defined.  This creates a technically infinite number of N's.  So, would this still be a valid $\Omega$ to be used in the Boltzmann's equation?

Comment: Hi Ted, Mathjax is used on this site for expressions such as the ones above and, as it makes any possible answers more likely, imo, it might be worth your while performing a quick edit. Best of luck with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Just learned Mathjax which was pretty easy.  Hopefully, some people will respond.

Comment: Also, I think that people answering your questions may be able to copy and paste your hard work, increasing the chances of an answer.

Comment: People are voting to put your question on hold, which may be because it's not really clear why you suspect this derivation may not be correct. If you could expand on that, I think it would improve the question considerably. We tend to be hard on questions that are just asking us to check something, partly as a measure to discourage people looking for homework help.

Comment: P.S. I fixed up the math formatting for you.

Comment: I know the mathematics is correct.   I am planning to use this derivation in my chem e. class for thermodynamics in two weeks.  I did this derivation myself.  However, since i have not seen this derivation anywhere on the web (including this website) or textbooks, I want to know why.  Did I set it up in a way that violates the laws of physics.  Also, if anyone sees this derivation anywhere else, that would be great as well.  It's such a simple derivation compared to the others, that there has to be a reason this is not used more commonly.

Comment: I really don't understand this site.  The reason for putting this on hold is because you suspect I need help for a homework question???  Here is my website and the schedule of classes for the thermodynamics class I am teaching.

Comment: http://web.csulb.edu/depts/enrollment/registration/class_schedule/Fall_2015/By_Subject/CHzE.html

Comment: https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/che/views/faculty/yu.shtml

Comment: I just don't understand the review system here.  Typically, there should be some sort of Peer-Review where the reviewers pose their concerns and there is some sort of rebuttal.  If you have concerns, email me at ted.yu@csulb.edu and let's hash this out professionally.  This is the first time I have used this site, and the experience so far has not been good, except for the nice response by David Z and Acid Jazz.

Comment: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~tedhyu/

Comment: I concur that this is not a "Please derive this for me" type question that we [consider off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5968/25301); it is instead asking "Why isn't this common" which makes it off-topic as it is [asking for opinions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) about something.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look [at the Help Center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help) as it can explain the SE model a whole lot better than I could do in a ~500 character comment box.

Comment: Ted Yu - My vote to close (which happened, by chance, to be the last one) was because, in the initial version(s) (up to revision 6), it was simply about a derivation, which in this case is homework-like, while not an actual homework problem. The current version (revision 7) makes it clearer that it is really just about the concept involved, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the vote (or unvote) of confidence HDE.  Your unvote still does not open this question though.

Comment: Kyle:  The question is not why isn't this common, but is the derivation valid?  The assumption that people make is that it is correct, just because the answer is correct.  A simpler derivation can save a lot of lecture time, as well as time for the students to grasp a concept.  But I am being careful to not introduce a simple derivation if it has flaws.  I understand now why this board has issues with this question, because most just assume the derivation is correct because of the correct answer.  In a way, you are taking short cuts much like the person who comes here seeking free answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues with that derivation:

- You're missing the extra term $\frac 52 k N,$ which may matter if you have to do any work with chemical potentials.
- Your students will not necessarily know why to parcel the space into volumes of size $\lambda^3$. Starting from the definition of entropy and deriving that the thermal volume $\lambda^3$ is important seems preferable.
- Your students may benefit from knowing that half-factorials exist via $n! = \int_0^\infty dx~x^n~e^{-x},$ that they start from $(-1/2)! = \sqrt{\pi},$ and that the volume of an $n$-ball of radius $r$ is $\pi^{n/2} ~ r^n / (n/2)!.$ It is only about fifteen minutes or less on a chalkboard of mathematical trickery, but it can help to facilitate some later calculations, plus an "oh, that's how that works" explaining why Gaussians have these mysterious factors of $\sqrt{\pi}$ in them.
- The fact that quantum mechanics makes particles *even-in-principle indistinguishable* is huge, and it resolves the Gibbs paradox, leading to the Sackur-Tetrode equation. Robbing a student of this fact, and the amount of brain-warp that it creates, is not a *bad* thing necessarily, but it's also not necessarily a *good* thing. This is an opportunity to plant a seed of cognitive dissonance that only really will get resolved when the student learns quantum field theory. It is maybe even *the* central problem with particle-centric understandings of the world.
- If you're teaching statistical mechanics, your students just barely are beginning to understand what temperature really is. I'm not sure I personally would make it a "load-bearing beam" of their understanding of statistical mechanics. For learning thermodynamics prior to a statistical mechanics course, sure, just treat temperature as a phenomenological given, we can measure it with a thermometer, who cares what it is? But now that you have an ability to talk about how $\beta = (k_B T)^{-1}$ deals much better with "negative temperatures" than $T$ does, everything that the student knows from earlier thermodynamics courses is painfully incomplete and you may not want to rest too much material on a good understanding of temperature and the thermal wavelength.

With all of this said: your approach is certainly simple and clean, and might make a good heuristic introduction to the topic if you do not want to devote a whole lecture to the Sackur-Tetrode equation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and it is great to get your perspective.  My students are chemical engineering majors, and the biggest challenge is to help them understand the 2nd law and why heat is related to entropy (or randomness).  I will use the concept of the quantum volume, $\lambda^3$ to relate this.  The one issue I see from your feedback is that you need entropy to derive quantum volume.  The thermal wavelength can be derived by $\Lambda = \frac h p $,  $E_k = \frac {p^2} {2m}$,  $E_k = \pi k_B T$.  Do you mean one of these equations require S to derive?

Comment: CR Drost:  I've been thinking about this comment you made:  "You're missing the extra term (5/2)kN, which may matter if you have to do any work with chemical potentials."  Are you referring to the fact that I do not derive the correct chemical potential definition if I leave out the 5/2 term for entropy?

Comment: @TedYu I believe so. Certainly the expression $\mu = T {\left({\partial S\over\partial N}\right)}_{E,V}$ would seem to depend crucially on it.

Comment: The chemical potential of an ideal monoatomic gas should be:   $\mu = \tau ln \frac {n}
{n_Q}$http://web.mit.edu/ndhillon/www/Teaching/Physics/bookse5.html

Curiously, I get this result if I leave out the 5/2 term with your above definition of chemical potential.  Which is why I am confused about your comment.  I don't understand why you need the 5/2 term to get the correct chemical potential.

Comment: I posed the question here if you are interested:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231080/extra-5-2-tau-term-in-chemical-potential-of-a-monoatomic-ideal-gas

Comment: @TedYu: You need that term because the expression you're deriving is $k N \ln(\alpha U^{3/2} V N^{-5/2})$ and the derivative of $N \log N$ is $\log N + 1$, so you really get $k \ln (\alpha U^{3/2} V) + \frac{-5}2 k(\ln N + 1),$ the extra $-5/2 k$ needs to be balanced by a $+5/2 k$ to get the result you seek.

Comment: I trust you are right, but I still can't get over the fact that U is independent of N.  If U = $\frac 3 2 N k_B T$, it would cancel all the N dependence inside the log in the case where it is constant P.  But I guess in this case, it is constant E (or U), so I get it.  Still stumped on the other question though.